# get Users list of folder in google drive api

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

Is there an api  to get the list of users memebers with their role related to a drive folder?

i tried with get list of permission but in debug doesn't work

```
 PermissionsResource.ListRequest listPermissions= service.Permissions.List(fileId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer :

```
  var request = service.Files.Get(fileId);

            request.SupportsAllDrives = true;
            request.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
            request.Fields = "*";

            IList<Permission> listPermission = request.Execute().Permissions;
```